# Menu Interface Student Record System

Tags: java, loops, interface, menu

I have a partially working record system, but I'm having trouble with the menu interface. Basically, the menu should allow you to:

1. Add a Student
2. Delete a Student
3. Print Students
4. Quit

Now the menu works fine but I'm having trouble with the Add Student section. When they add a student they require:

- A Prompt for first name
- A prompt for surname
- A prompt for ID number

When they have done this, it asks if they want to add another; if "y" is entered, it loops again, and if "n" is entered it goes back to the main menu.

Now on mine when they press "n" nothing happens, and when you press y, it loops again but it won't let you enter any values for the first name.

Here's all the code for the System:

REGISTRYINTERFACE.java

```
/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author parry2411 
 */
package student;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RegistryInterface
    {

        private Registry theRegistry = new Registry();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        public RegistryInterface(Registry theRegistry)
        {
        }

        public void doMenu()
        {
            boolean done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("\nRegistry Main Menu\n*******************\n");
                    System.out.println("1. Add a Student \n2. Delete a Student"
                            + "\n3. Print Registry\n0. Quit");

                    System.out.println("Select Option [1, 2, 3, 0] :>");
                    String userDecission = input.nextLine();

                    int decission = Integer.parseInt(userDecission);

                    switch (decission)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("System Closing Down..");
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            doAddStudent();
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            doDeleteStudent();
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            doPrintRegistry();
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter in a valid"
                                    + " Menu Option");
                            doMenu();
                            break;
                    }
                    done = true;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Value Entered, Try Again....");
                }
            }
        }


    private void doAddStudent()
        {
            String addMore;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("\nAdd New Student\n***********\n");

                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Students Forename :>");
                    String fName = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter Student Surname :>");
                    String sName = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number :>");
                    int idNum = input.nextInt();

                    theRegistry.addStudent(new Student(fName, sName, idNum));

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nERROR OCCURED: Incorect Value Entered"
                            + "\nTry Again... \nStudent Was NOT added");
                }


                System.out.println("\nAdd Another Student (Y/N) : >");
                addMore = input.next();



            } while (!"n".equals(addMore));
        }

        private void doDeleteStudent()
        {
            String another;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("\nDelete Student\n***********\n");
                System.out.println("Enter Student ID To Delete :>");
                try
                {
                    int studID = input.nextInt();
                    theRegistry.deleteStudent(studID);

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nERROR OCCURED: Incorect Value Entered"
                            + "\nTry Again...\n");
                }

                System.out.println("\nDelete Another? (Y/N)");
                another = input.next();


            } while (!"n".equals(another));
        }

        private void doPrintRegistry()
        {

            System.out.println("\nPrinting Registry\n***********\n");

            if(theRegistry.studentList.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The Student Record System Contains No Student"
                        + " Records, Please Add Students\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println(theRegistry.format()); 
                System.out.println("\n****Printing Finished........");
            }

            doMenu();

        }
    }
```

REGISTRY.java

```
/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author parry2411 
 */
package student;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Registry
{
    public LinkedList<Student> studentList = new LinkedList<>();
    public Iterator<Student> iter = studentList.iterator();

    public Registry()
    {
    }

    public void addStudent(Student aStudent)
    {
        Iterator<Student> addIterator = studentList.iterator();

        while (addIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = addIterator.next();
            if (ob.getStudentID() == aStudent.getStudentID())
            {
                System.out.println("This Student ID "
                        + ""+ aStudent.getStudentID()+ " Is Already Used"
                        + "\n Try Adding Again......");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student "+ aStudent.getForeName() + " "
                + "" + aStudent.getSurName() +" "
                + "Successfully Added To System.....");

        studentList.addLast(aStudent);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(int studentID)
    {
        Iterator<Student> deleteIterator = studentList.iterator();
        boolean removed = false;

        while(deleteIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = deleteIterator.next();

            if(ob.getStudentID() == studentID)
            {
                deleteIterator.remove();
                removed = true;
                System.out.println(ob.getForeName() + " " + ob.getSurName() + " Was Succesffully Removed from System. \n");
            }
        }
        if(!removed)
        {
            System.out.println("Student ID not found");
        }
    }

    public String format()
    {
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Student> formatIterator = studentList.iterator();

        while(formatIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = formatIterator.next();
            sB.append(ob.format());      
        }
        return sB.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        Iterator<Student> toStringIterator = studentList.iterator();
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();

        while(toStringIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = toStringIterator.next();
            sB.append(ob.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        return sB.toString();
    }
}
```

REGISTRY APP

```
package student;

public class RegistryApp
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Registry theRegistry = new Registry();
        RegistryInterface aRegInterface = new RegistryInterface(theRegistry);
        aRegInterface.doMenu();   
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author parry2411
 * Date Created: 18-Mar-2013
 */

package student;

public class Student 
{
    private String foreName;
    private String surName;
    private int studentID;


    public Student(String foreName, String surName, int studentID)
    {
        this.foreName = foreName;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getForeName()
    {
        return foreName;
    }

    public void setForeName(String foreName)
    {
        this.foreName = foreName;
    }

    public String getSurName()
    {
        return surName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName)
    {
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public int getStudentID()
    {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID)
    {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getSimpleName()+"{" + "foreName=" + foreName + ", surName=" + surName + ", studentID=" + studentID + '}';
    }

    public String format()
    {
        return String.format("%-5s %-5s \t\t %-5d \n",foreName,surName,studentID);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) with a trimmed version of your code that reflects the problem?

Comment: Basically the error is at the RegistryInterface class, I am unable to cut it down to be honest, as the problem might be everytwhere in that class.

Comment: Yes, it might be anywhere - that's the point: if you can localize the problem, you may be able to solve it without even posting a question. Try reading the SSCCE page [here](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `doAddStudent` method to this way:

```
private void doAddStudent()
    {
        String addMore;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nAdd New Student\n***********\n");

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Students Forename :>");
                String fName = input.next();//use next() instead of nextLine()

                System.out.println("Enter Student Surname :>");
                String sName = input.next();//use next() instead of nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number :>");
                int idNum = input.nextInt();

                theRegistry.addStudent(new Student(fName, sName, idNum));

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\nERROR OCCURED: Incorect Value Entered"
                        + "\nTry Again... \nStudent Was NOT added");
            }


            System.out.println("\nAdd Another Student (Y/N) : >");
            addMore = input.next();



        } while (!"n".equals(addMore));
    }
```

You was getting error because of `Scanner.nextLine()` you was using .Now the Question is  **Why**?
[`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) as described in official document is:

> **Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.** This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

`Scanner.next()` doesn't properly terminates the allocated line of memory. So when `nextLine()` is called via `String fName = input.nextLine();` after `addMore = input.next();` after user inputs `y` it is actually terminating the previous line that actually had value in it -- entered via `next()` rather than taking in a new `String` value.That's why it was skipping the entry from user . So , in order to carry on reading the entered value rather than the previous blank line (because of non-termination of value returned by `next()`) you can use [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) which according to official document states that:

> **Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.**

**UPDATE** 
You should also replace :

```
String userDecission = input.nextLine();
```

to

```
String userDecission = input.next();
```

Comment: This has worked, But when i press n for add more, it should load the menu, Is this just a case on adding an If statement there?